# How to fix Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_cli_args() in class-wp-importer.php

Tags: plugins, php, fatal-error

I'm getting the following error:

> `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_cli_args() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-admin\includes\class-wp-importer.php:276) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-admin\includes\class-wp-importer.php on line 276`

```php
function get_cli_args( $param, $required = false ) {
    $args = $_SERVER['argv'];
    if ( ! is_array( $args ) ) {
        $args = array();
    }
    // ...
}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: When this error occurred, what were you trying to do? Please add more details.

Answer (score 3):

Are you somehow including `wp-admin\includes\class-wp-importer.php` using `include` or `require`? That may cause the error of `get_cli_args()` function declared twice.

If that is the case, then you better use `include_once` or `require_once`.

Also, perhaps you should test your installation by disabling all the plugins and any custom theme. Then activate the theme and test WordPress. Then activate one plugin at a time and test each time to see if the error appears. This will show if this error is caused by any plugin or theme.